# Does an unbounded operator have its norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

We define norm of a linear transformation $T$ as $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|$. If $\|Tx\|$ of an unbounded operator $T$ is bounded on $\|x\|=1$, then can we define the norm of $T$ as $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|$?

Comment: In your second sentence how do you define an unbounded operator ?

Comment: if $T$ is linear then the behavior of $T$ is determined by the image of $T$ in the unit ball. Then if the norm is finite in this ball $T$ is bounded.

Comment: @Masacroso It means unbounded operators cant have their norms?

Comment: If the norm doesn't exit then the norm doesn't exist, tautologically. On the other hand, the name *unbounded operator* can be applied to any  linear function from a linear subspace of a Banach $X$ to a Banach $Y$. Such operators can be bounded and therefore have finite norm.

Comment: @Infinity I mean what supinf answered below.

Answer (score 6):

If $\|Tx \|$ is bounded on $\{ x: \| x\| =1\}$
then $T$ is already bounded, so $T$ cannot be unbounded.

In this case, yes, you can define the norm of $T$ like you suggested.

Edit: an unbounded operator has no norm (if that was your question), because
$\sup_{\| x \|=1} \| Tx \| =\infty$

Comment: Actually I want to know that norm of an unbounded operator exists or not?

Comment: @Infinity As user Youem asked before: How do you define an unbounded operator?

Comment: If $T$ is unbounded, then $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|= \infty$. Hence $||T||$ does not exist.

Comment: @Fred So we can say, $sup_{||x||=c} ||Tx||=infinity$ for any $c>0$

Comment: Yes. Try to prove: $\sup_{||x||=c} ||Tx||=c \sup_{||x||=1} ||Tx||$